# Keras CNN too few parameters

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, keras, keras-layer, conv-neural-network

I am trying to recreate the following tutorial CNN with 3 inputs and sigmoid activation functions in keras:

[image]

So the number of parameters should be 7 (assuming 1 filter of size 2 convolved over 2 locations (either top 2 inputs or 2 lower inputs), 2 shared weights (shown as 1.0's on the synapses) and no padding in the conv1d layer). When I write the following in Keras:

[image]

I only get 5 parameters when I check it in `model.summary()`:

[image]

What do I need to do to get the correct number of parameters? There are probably several things that are wrong in my code since I'm new to Keras.

Comment: Please don't post code as pictures.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All convolutional parameters are shared spatially (in case of 1D this means across the input sequence). Precisely, the convolutional filter of length `2` is applied twice to inputs `(x[0], x[1])` and `(x[1], x[2])`, but it's the same filter in both cases and correspondingly the trainable parameters are the same too.

This explains the size of the model you are getting right now: `Conv1D` has 3 parameters (weight `(2)` and bias `(1)`), the dense layer has 2 parameters because the output of `Conv1D` is `(?, 2, 1)`.

Finally, I can't comment on the network you're trying to implement. Probably they mean 2 filters (but then the layer will have 6 parameters)... But I'm not aware of any implementation, in which the convolutional layer has separate parameters for each patch.

Comment: Ok thanks! it's my drawing and I realize now that there should only be 1 bias synapse for the conv1d layer, double checked it in the literature.  I still don't get why there are 2 but not 3 parameters in the dense layer: There are 2 conv1d outputs but what about the bias that also has to be trained?

Comment: Oh, one correction: the dense layer includes the bias - it has 1 weight and 1 bias. But the wiring isn't conventional though, because usually the input to the dense layer has rank 2, which means that `(?, 2, 1)` should be reshaped to `(?, 2)` via flattening. I thought keras does it automatically, but it doesn't, so you have to add `Flatten` layer yourself. That would lead to 3 parameters in the dense layer, to the total of 6.